# Allowing for changes in element height during a scroll animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation, css-position

Got a JS/JQuery issue I'm struggling to solve.

I'm building a simple one page site with a fixed header and anchor based scrolling navigation. When a user clicks a link the the scrollTop of the body is animated to the top of the relevant section. Included in this function is a calculation that subtracts the height of the header from the scroll distance to ensure the fixed header doesn't obscure the top of the section

The issue I'm having is because of a separate function that applies a class to the header if a user scrolls past a certain distance. This class causes a few properties to change and therefore the height of the header element changes.

This means that the value of `$('header').outerHeight();` at the end of the scrolling animation is smaller than what it was when the animation began. This change means that the distance scrolled is wrong and the window ends up slightly too short of the desired location.

How do I allow for this change in value during the scrolling animation? Ideally I want everything to stay dynamic rather than specifying fixed heights/sizes. TIA.

```js
$('a[href^="#"]').on("click", function() {

  let headerHeight = $('header').outerHeight();

  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top - headerHeight
  }, 500);
});

$(window).on('load resize scroll', function() {


  if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 100 ) { // this refers to window
    $('header').addClass('scroll');
  } else {
    $('header').removeClass('scroll');
  }

});
```

```css
body,html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
header {
  padding: 30px 30px;
  position:fixed;
  left:0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index:99;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

header h1 {
 display:inline-block;
 width:10%;
  color: white;
}

header.scroll {
  background: black;
  padding: 15px 30px;
}

header nav {
  display:inline-block;
  width: 89%;
}

header nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-align:right;
}

header nav ul li {
  display:inline-block;

}

header nav ul li a {
  color: white;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.hero {
  height: 600px;
  background: blue;
}

section h2 {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

section {
  height: 600px;
}

#one {
  background: red;
}

#two {
  background: green;
}

#three {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>

  <h1>Title</h1>

  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#one">Section 1 </a></li>
      <li><a href="#two">Section 2 </a></li>
      <li><a href="#three">Section 3 </a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

</header>

<section class="hero"><h2>Hero</h2></section>
<section id="one"><h2>Section 1</h2></section>
<section id="two"><h2>Section 2</h2></section>
<section id="three"><h2>Section 3</h2></section>
```

If you run the above snippet and click on the link for "Section 1" at the top of the page. You can see the distance scrolled is slightly too short and the bottom of the `.hero` element is still visible due to the change in height.

Comment: The snippet you've added is not working.

Comment: @Prawinsoni It wasn't intended to be a working example, just to show my various bits of code, apologies. Have amended the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up solving this by adding a callback to my animation function. The callback checks if the height of the header has changed since the function was first called and if it has, then the scrollTop is increased by this amount.

```
$('a[href^="#"]').on("click", function() {

  let headerHeightOne = $('header').outerHeight();

  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top - headerHeightOne
  }, 500, function() {
    let headerHeightTwo = $('header').outerHeight();
    let difference =  headerHeightOne - headerHeightTwo;

    if (difference > 0 ) {
      $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: $(window).scrollTop() + difference
      }, 100);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I feel this as a workaround because you're scrolling it twice, not a good idea for performance. I'm not getting if changing the header height's logic is in your hand why can't you just use it.

Comment: Have explained multiple times I don’t want to hard code the value because it would have to recalculated over and over as the dimensions change. It will also only work on the first scroll animation as after this the change is triggered. Once that change is triggered the header height will have reduced meaning that the calculation now needs to be removed. This means I’d have to write many more functions and conditionals to allow for this whereas the above solution is much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I'm subtracting 30 from header's height because in start padding was "30px 30px" and then it's going to be "15px 30px" means header height should be:
height = actualHeight -  - ,
and this required when your header is expanded(means header does not have class scroll) so I added condition.

```js
$('a[href^="#"]').on("click", function() {

  let headerHeight = $('header').outerHeight();
  if(!$('header').hasClass('scroll')) {
    headerHeight -= 30; //The padding removed
  }

  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top - headerHeight
  }, 500);
});

$(window).on('load resize scroll', function() {


  if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 100 ) { // this refers to window
    $('header').addClass('scroll');
  } else {
    $('header').removeClass('scroll');
  }

});
```

```css
body,html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
header {
  padding: 30px 30px;
  position:fixed;
  left:0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index:99;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

header h1 {
 display:inline-block;
 width:10%;
  color: white;
}

header.scroll {
  background: black;
  padding: 15px 30px;
}

header nav {
  display:inline-block;
  width: 89%;
}

header nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-align:right;
}

header nav ul li {
  display:inline-block;

}

header nav ul li a {
  color: white;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.hero {
  height: 600px;
  background: blue;
}

section h2 {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

section {
  height: 600px;
}

#one {
  background: red;
}

#two {
  background: green;
}

#three {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>

  <h1>Title</h1>

  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#one">Section 1 </a></li>
      <li><a href="#two">Section 2 </a></li>
      <li><a href="#three">Section 3 </a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

</header>

<section class="hero"><h2>Hero</h2></section>
<section id="one"><h2>Section 1</h2></section>
<section id="two"><h2>Section 2</h2></section>
<section id="three"><h2>Section 3</h2></section>
```

Comment: Thanks for this but I'm already aware of why this happens, what I need is a way to take the change into account. It also needs to be dynamic and not hard coded as the padding will change across various screen sizes.

Comment: How will you make the header padding dynamic? You can use the same login to calculate the height.

Comment: Header padding will change across breakpoints which means continually updating the calculation in the JS too. Have posted an easier solution above.